# Unable to share text to Whatsapp in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

When sharing text to Whatsapp on iOS 8 and below this code is working fine, but while sharing on iOS 9 it is not working.

```
- (IBAction)btnWhatsApp:(id)sender {
    NSString *msg = shareText;
    NSString *urlWhats = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@",msg];
    NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlWhats stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WhatsApp not installed." message:@"Your device has no WhatsApp installed." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:NO];
    [viewShare setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `iOS 9`, `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`  need for any call, ensure once are you added the following information in youre `.plist`:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
 <array>
  <string>whatsapp</string>
 </array>
```

then try

Comment: Thanks it work....

Comment: @PPreeti - happy to hear this

Answer (score 1):

If you build for iOS 9 or above you need to whitelist the schemes your app will query.

[image]

Comment: any key for opening message app?

Comment: @Nij you wouldn't go about opening messages this way. Use `MFMessageComposeViewController` https://developer.apple.com/reference/messageui/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller